# How do I unset the comment form in Drupal 7?

Tags: forms, comments

In Drupal 7, the comment form appears on every node. I want to unset the comment form and display a link of "Add new comment" that will display the comment form on click.

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Structure > Content types", "Content type > Comment settings", and uncheck "Show reply form on same page as comments."